# meaning of "sw" on map

Tags: meaning

I guess this sentence is both grammatical and idiomatic.

> VOA is located at 330 Independence Avenue.

[image]

The street is labeled ad "Independence Ave SW" On Google map. What does "SW" stand for? Is it a combination of the first letter of some words?

play.google.com describes

> **SW** Maps is a free GIS and mobile mapping app for collecting, presenting and sharing geographic information.

It seems like "SW" is a brand, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"SW" stands for "South West". Note that the label on the tack says "330 Independence Avenue Southwest".

Streets in the US are often numbered outward from a central point. So for example if the street runs north and south, the buildings north of the center point may be numbered "1 N", "2 N", "3 N", etc, while the buildings south of the center point are numbered "1 S", "2 S", "3 S", and so on.

Usually the numbers are labeled N and S or W and E, even if the street runs at an angle. Washington DC does it a little different. Streets that run east and west and that are north of the Mall -- i.e. the big open area in the center of the city -- are labeled NW and NE, while streets that are south of the Mall are labeled SW and SE. That is, "Independence Ave SW" means that it's on a street named "Independence Avenue", that this street is south of the mall, and that it is west of the center point of the street. (The center being basically the center line of the Mall.)

(Not relevant to this question, but: buildings on one side of the street are normally given even numbers while those on the other side are given odd numbers. And decades ago, buildings would be numbered consecutively. That is, one side would be 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, etc, while the other side would be 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, etc. Today buildings are usually numbered with gaps, so that if a new building is put up between two existing buildings, it can be given a number in between. Often the number is the number of yards from the starting point, but not necessarily.)

This has nothing to do with "SW Maps". I'm not familiar with SW Maps, but a quick look at their web site shows that the manufacturer is named "SoftWel", so I'd guess the "SW" in their name is short for "SoftWel". As far as I know it's just a coincidence that SW can stand for both SoftWel and South West and that both are applicable to maps.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive explanation. Does "the Mall" in your answer refer to the National Mall?

Comment: "National Mall": Yes.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is there on the map, a couple of inches to the right, where the big red pointer is at the address 330 Independence Avenue Southwest.
 SW of course is an abbreviation of southwest.

SW Maps is not related to this use. It refers to Softwel, a company that publishes the app.

Comment: Thank you. The "SW" in "Independence Ave SW" means [The Southwestern United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southwestern_United_States), right?

Comment: No, it refers to the southwest quarter of the city of Washington D.C., which is the area pictured in the map.